# Doesn't the "untagged" tag defeat the purpose?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today, I noticed a new tag called "untagged." Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the tagging system? How do you flag a tag for removal?

Comment: That actually means all tags on that question have been deleted, so it should be tagged by anyone with sufficient rep to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged) because the question had a tag which was burninated. You can either edit it and tag it to what's relevant or flag the post.